# blender trackpad behaviour on windows as on a mac

Tags: mouse

I switched from a macbook to a windows laptop.
All I can do with the trackpad is zoom in and out.
Is there anyway to get the same behaviour as on a mac?

Answer (score 2):

Zoom in/out: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>LMB</kbd> and move on the touchpad.

Move the view: <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>LMB</kbd> and move on the touchpad.

Rotate the view: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>LMB</kbd> and move on the touchpad.

For all that you need to check this option:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it helps, but it's way better on a mac.

Comment: Well, it's up to your opinion. Use this setting from years and this is really fast (few movements to do between touchpad and keys).

Comment: I don't say it's not fast. It is different from the mac behavior. But that might be due to hardware limitations.

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest I have come to Mac navigation on windows. You only use one finger. Maybe this is bad in some other way but give it a try.

[image]